# How to solve an error 500 in heroku/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, internal-server-error

My app is working fine in localhost but it returns error 500: internal server error when i run in Heroku. It says, "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

I have this under my routes.rb

```
  get 'employees/showemployees'
  resources :employees
```

and this, under my controller

```
def showemployees
str = params[:str]
render json: @employee = Employee.where('fname LIKE ? OR lname LIKE ? OR mname LIKE ? OR username LIKE ? or id LIKE ?',
       "%#{str}%","%#{str}%","%#{str}%", "%#{str}%", "%#{str}%")
```

end

when i type http://localhost:3000/employees/showemployees?str=samplename
it displays a json format of the record but when i type https://dtitdtr.herokuapp.com/employees/showemployees?str=samplename
it will return the error 500

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

is already done yet still,

Comment: see the heroku logs, `heroku addons:upgrade logging:expanded` and then `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: @Sontya it says, Add-on plan not found.

Comment: type this and see the errors `heroku logs -n 1000`

Comment: @Sontya  it says,  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: @Sontya it says, error in line 6 which is     render json: 'at'employee = Employee.where('fname LIKE ? OR lname LIKE ? OR mname LIKE ? OR username LIKE ? or id LIKE ?',

Comment: i think it's pointing towards 'id LIKE...'

Comment: yes, what is that `id`, rails adds one unique `id` for each record then what's that `id`

Comment: that is the generated one @Sontya

Comment: it went just fine when running in localhost @Sontya

Comment: try removing, `id` comparison and just look for fname, lname, mname and username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

i just added `i` in `LIKE` clause like this `ILIKE` and have the code this way

```
render json: @employee = Employee.where('fname ILIKE ? OR lname ILIKE ? OR mname ILIKE ? OR username ILIKE ?',
   "%#{str}%","%#{str}%","%#{str}%", "%#{str}%")
```

it won't work in `localhost` but it works in `heroku`. So when running this app in `localhost`, the above code should have no `i` before the `LIKE`clause but when running this in `heroku`, `ILIKE` should be used instead of simple `LIKE` because when using `LIKE` clause only in `heroku`, it will be case sensitive...

and by the way, `id` was removed.